# importing data from csv files(with headers) using sprintf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have 400 csv files which have a particular name with sequence as M_0000-RN.csv, M_0001-RN.csv, M_0002-RN.csv..and so on. I am having trouble in importing all of them (perhaps a mistake in using proper file identifier) and then I need to process the files together in a loop.

```
        myFolder = 'XYZ';
        filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.csv');
        csvFiles   = dir(filePattern);
        for k = 1:length(csvFiles)
        mydata = cell(1, length(csvfiles);
        myfilename = sprintf('M_%d-RN.csv', k);
        mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);
        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *zero-padded* integer so you'll want to use `%04d` instead to make sure that your integer has at least 4 digits and zero-pads the rest. Also, if they start with `0000` you'll want to subtract `1` from `k`.

```
myfilename = sprintf('M_%04d-RN.csv', k - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! It saved me big time :)

Comment: @Ritz If this answer solves your problem, consider [marking it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of this answer, to turn it green so that the community may know that your problem is solved.

Comment: I did it now. Thank you :)